# differential map of a function between smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be a function between manifolds. If $df_p=0$ at all points $p \in M$, can we say that $f$ is a constant function? I think it would be but have not been able to prove it since I am a beginner in differential geometry.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to suppose $M$ is connected (see if you can find an easy counterexample if $M$ is not).

Let $p,q\in M$ and $\gamma$ a regular path connecting $p$ and $q$, say $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$. The function $f\circ\gamma$ is a path in $N$. Its derivative is $df\circ\gamma' = 0,$ so the function $f\circ\gamma$ is a constant map. In particular, $f(p) = f(q)$. Therefore $f$ is constant.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how Picard-Lindelof implies that $f\circ \gamma$ is constant?

Comment: @EricAuld I was thinking to appeal to uniqueness, but I think the reference may be too broad or misplaced, so I altered the answer.

Comment: Thanks for explanation..but in some books i have seen that a manifold is defined as a connected paracompact hausdorff space locally homeomorphic to euclidean space,for eg in the book Riemannian geometry & geometric analysis by jurgen jost.I get  confuse for the definition also , which definition is generally used for manifolds?

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to show that it is constant on the domain of each chart (use that the charts are bijections). Then since the charts are an open cover... :) I think you will need $M$ connected (you also need the domain connected in the case of a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$).